# Opening a native dialog box in Android Google Chrome redirecting to the app on Google Play

Tags: android, google-chrome, web, google-play, progressive-web-apps

Recently I encountered [a website](https://radiofarda.com) that made the Android Google Chrome display a "native" dialog box advising the users to use the Android application instead. Notice that the Install button opens the app's page in the Google Play app and has nothing to do with PWAs in any way. How did they do such a thing?

[image]